# How to find the wave function of the ground state in the case of a non-orthogonal basis set?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, operators, wavefunction, density-operator, orbitals

This question is a continuation of my previous question https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/281856/

I have the Gaussian basis set, this basis is non-orthogonal. In the case of non-orthogonal basis set to find min Energy I have to solve the next equation:

$$H\vec{\psi}=EB\vec{\psi}$$ where $H$ is a Hamiltonian matrix $B$ is a matrix of  overlap integrals: $$B_{i,j}=\langle\psi_i|\psi_j\rangle.$$

Questions:

1. Do I understand correctly that, as in the case of orthogonal basis set, the wave function of the ground state has the following form?
   $$\psi_{gs}=\sum_i {c_i\psi_i}$$ where $\psi_i$ are the basis functions, $c_i$ are the ground state eigenvector components
2. The ground state energy ($E_{min}$) can now be calculated as follows?
   $$E_{gs}=\langle\psi_{gs}|H|\psi_{gs}\rangle$$ Those does the overlap integrals no longer participate in obtaining the ground state?
3. I would like to get the average of some operator, for example the square of the coordinate on the ground state functions:

$$\langle r^2\rangle=\langle\psi_{gs}|r^2|\psi_{gs}\rangle$$In this case, the overlap integrals also do not participate in this expression in any way?

**Following the AXensen's answer:**

After the equation is solved $H\vec{\psi}=EB\vec{\psi}$  there is a set of the eigenvalues and the set of the eigenvectors components, but these eigenvectors are not normalized yet. Let's take a look at eigenvector normalization with a particular example:

Let the basis consist of two functions $\psi_1$ and $\psi_2$, then $\begin{pmatrix}
  B_{11} & B_{12}\\
  B_{21}& B_{22}
\end{pmatrix}$ is the overlap integrals matrix. $c_1$, $c_2$ are the eigenvector components. 
Then, in order to find the normalization coefficient, it is necessary to solve the following equation:

$$\begin{pmatrix}
  N*c_{1}^* & N*c_{2}^*
\end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix}
  B_{11} & B_{12}\\
  B_{21}& B_{22}
\end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix}
  N*c_{1} \\ N*c_{2}
\end{pmatrix}=1$$

After that it will be possible to write down normalized wave function (for example the wave function of ground state): $\psi_{gs}=N(c_{1}\psi_1+c_{2}\psi_2)$

Comment: (1.) is actually answered in the thread linked (it serves for deriving the first equation in your question)

Comment: @AXensen, thanks! I have asked question below your answer, please have a look at it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As long as your groundstate is normalized, which is not the same thing as $\sum |c_i|^2=1$, then everything you said is correct.

The condition is instead:

$$
\langle \psi_{gs}|\psi_{gs}\rangle=1
$$
Which can be written conveniently as
$$
\vec{c}_i^TB\vec{c}_i=1
$$
or alternatively as
$$
\sum_{ij}c_j^*c_i\langle \psi_i|\psi_j\rangle
$$
Which is the same thing - almost by the definition of the matrix $B$. Also be aware that for similar reasons,
$$
\langle \psi_{gs}|H|\psi_{gs}\rangle\neq|c_i|^2\langle\psi_i|H|\psi_i\rangle
$$

Comment: Thanks! Could you write how the ground state wavefunction needs to be normalized in this case? Since it's not the same as $∑|c_i|^2=1$

Comment: @MamMam done. edited my answer

Comment: Thank you very much for the details! I have edited my question and added part with the particular example, which describes wave function normalization. Could you please look at this part. Did I understand your explanation correctly?

Comment: @MamMam looks good to me